# Rails, Database reset on Git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, openshift

Update: My production database was actually set to sqlite as well. Nevertheless, it does not explain the wipe...?

Original:

I am presently following Michael Hartl's [Rail tutorial](http://railstutorial.org), almost to the letter. The only difference is that I am using OpenShift to deploy my app, with a PostgreSQL cartridge. Unfortunately, everytime I am doing a push to openshift, the server restarts my app (normal), and my database is wiped (not normal, I think?). Then I have to rerun all the migrations, and fill up the database again. I also noticed that if I do a pull from OpenShift, then my local database (sqlite on my computer) is also wiped.

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails',        '4.2.0.rc1'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',   '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',     '>= 2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',     '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.0.beta2'   
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '~> 2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',        '1.3.9'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'web-console',        '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring',         '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'unicorn',    '4.8.3'
end
```

here is my .gitignore:

```
# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp
```

and here is my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Thanks in advance for your help, all suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your application is using the sqlite database instead of the postgresql one, double check your database configuration.  Also make sure you don't have any code with your migrations that would wipe out and recreate the database (like "test" settings").  Maybe post a "sanitized" version of your database yml file?

Every time you git push your application, it wipes out where your sqlite database is stored. If you want to use sqlite, you need to store it in your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, but we recommend using mysql or postgres instead so your application can be scaled if you want it to.

Comment: Okay, it is actually using sqlite in production (see update). But since .sqlite3 files are ignored by git, why is it wiped anyway?

Comment: I just realized I have been messing with Git branches lately; maybe production.sqlite3 was uploaded blank several times in a row, and I just did not realize it wouldn't happen next time. I'll retry, and very likely accept your answer very soon.

Comment: Every time you git push your application, it wipes out where your sqlite database is stored.  If you want to use sqlite, you need to store it in your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, but we recommend using mysql or postgres instead so your application can be scaled if you want it to.

Comment: Indeed, I guess it was deleted. If you add your last comment to your answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!